# Set up Knockout ViewModel for validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am attempting to figure out how to use the knockoutjs validation plugin. Looking at the project site on github, there is a [getting started section](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation#getting-started) describing how to set up a view model with validation.  In this example the ViewModel is declared as an inline object (is this the correct terminology?) like so:

```
var myViewModel = ko.validatedObservable({
   property1: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
   property2: ko.observable().extend({ max: 10 })
});

console.log(myViewModel.isValid()); //false

myViewModel().property1('something');
myViewModel().property2(9);

console.log(myViewModel.isValid()); //true
```

However, I would like to set up my viewmodel using a function like this:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.property1 = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.property2 = ko.observable().extend({ max: 10 });
};

var viewModelInstance = new MyViewModel();
console.log(viewModelInstance.isValid()); //false

viewModelInstance.property1('something');
viewModelInstance.property2(9);

console.log(viewModelInstance.isValid()); //true
```

The problem is that I get a script error saying that my `viewModelInstance` object does not have a method `isValid`.

Comment: By using `ko.validatedObservable` you're adding a level of validation functionality to the object off-the-cuff (same way kojs makes getter/setting/display adjustments when you use `var foo = ko.observable('bar')` over just a `var foo = 'bar';`). To skip over this would remove the actual implementation leaving you with (essentially) just metadata without implementation. how about mimicing what's actually [being performed](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/Src/knockout.validation.js#L1082-L1096)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ko.validatedObservable() is the key to validation of viewModel. It creates all internal methods needed by the plugin (there is more than isValid). You can still create instances with function but try wrapping it in ko.validatedObservable() :

```
var viewModelInstance = ko.validatedObservable( new MyViewModel() );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition from the source code, and the only place it is used within the `knockout.validation.js` source.

`validatedObservable(`) is this – and this alone.

```
ko.validatedObservable = function (initialValue)
{
    if (!kv.utils.isObject(initialValue)) { return ko.observable(initialValue).extend({ validatable: true }); }

    var obsv = ko.observable(initialValue);
    obsv.errors = kv.group(initialValue);
    obsv.isValid = ko.observable(initialValue.isValid());   
    obsv.errors.subscribe(function (errors) {
        obsv.isValid(errors.length === 0);
    });
    debugger;

    return obsv;
};
```

In my experience it's more trouble than it's worth - for instance it doesn't have an option to specify 'deep' for the 'group' that is created and I think it's really only intended for simple 'single level' js objects.

if you have a complicated model you're better off just doing something like this and creating an array of objects you really want to validate:

```
    var validatables = [];

    // if credit card is payment then validate payment details + address
    if (this.paymentMethod() == "Credit Card")
    {
        validatables.push(this.paymentDetails);
        validatables.push(this.billingAddress);

        if (this.shipToBillingAddress() == false)
        {
            validatables.push(this.shippingAddress);
        }
    }

    var group = ko.validation.group(validatables, { deep: true });
```